# API RESTful Resource Naming

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I always have the doubt that you can see below when i need to create theresource URLs for a REST API. I wonder if some one can help me.

Let's suppose that i have two models.

- User
- Post

User can submit his own posts and can comment his own and another posts.

Main resources URLs for User would be:

```
GET  /users                     # Retrieve all users.
POST /users                     # Create a new user.
GET/DELETE/PUT /users/{user_id} # Get, remove and update an user.
```

Main resource URLs for Post would be:

```
GET  /posts                     # Retrieve all posts.
POST /posts                     # Create a new post.
GET/DELETE/PUT /posts/{post_id} # Get, remove and update a post.
```

My problem come when for example i want:

Top 10 submitters (filter for a parameter(external link, discussion, all)). The URL should be:

```
GET /users/top?type=ext
GET /users/top?type=disc
GET /users/top # for all
```

Or maybe it should be:

```
GET /users?top=ext
GET /users?top=disc
GET /users?top=all
```

The same but with posts:

Top 10 commented post (filter for a parameter(external link, discussion, all)). The URL should be:

```
GET /posts/comments?type=ext
GET /posts/comments?type=disc
GET /posts/comments # for all
```

Or maybe it should be:

```
GET /posts?top=ext
GET /posts?top=disc
GET /posts?top=all
```

Any of above options are good for you or it should be another way?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to think of the REST URI as a model representation in itself.

So `/users/top` doesn't make a lot of sense but `/posts/comments` seems to be fine (as comments could also be a different model). But for your case, I recommend other set of query parameters as they're widely used for filtering & sorting requests. So in your case, I'd recommend something like:

```
GET /users?sort=ext&order=desc&limit=10
```

which would help me understand that I'm requesting 10 `user` resources which have been sorted for `ext` in the `descending` order. (you can even change it to `type=ext` if you want)

Comment: I understand. But then i think than  second resource should be done similar to previous one`/posts?sort=ext&order=desc&limit=10`

Comment: The thing is, for example, django would map both `/posts` and `/posts?ort=ext&order=desc&limit=10` with same  URI and you have to deal with many parameters (in the same `get` method). So i don't know if it's the best solution

Comment: I think that is how it is supposed to be. Consider a scenario where you'd have some other filters later on, say you come up with a search box implementation which should now request for the first 25 users whose firstName is 'John'. Since you'd still be requesting the `users` resource, your API should look like `/users?firstName=John&limit=25`. It'll be the same 'get' method again. Could you see if this helps: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/ ?

Comment: Ok. I will try to follow that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As usual; REST doesn't care what spellings you use.

One place you might look for inspiration is... stack overflow itself.  Do these URI look familiar?

```
/questions?sort=newest
/questions?sort=featured
/questions?sort=votes
```

The API has [pretty decent documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), which will also offer hints at decent spellings to deal with paging and search ranges.

That said, IMDB takes a different approach - [The Shawshank Redemption](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/) uses a straight forward "I am an element of a collection" spelling

```
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/
```

But the [top rated titles](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top) of all time? they appear as a *chart*

```
http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
```

> But i want to know if there is a standard according to @Hawkes answer or there is no standard at all.

No standard at all; just local spelling conventions.  Which is, to some degree, part of the point of REST: the server can use whatever spellings for URI make sense, and the client just "follows its nose" based on its understanding of the processing rules for the media type and the data provided by the server.

Comment: OK. I've seen StackOverflow documentation and some of the resources seem to match with what it supossed to be a standard but anothers don't. For example, `questions/{id}/answers/add` # Creates an answer on the given question. It think that should be just `questions/{id}/answers` (a POST). But i want to know if there is a standard according to @Hawkes answer or there is no standard at all.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time.